# Stretches to prevent shin splints

Tags: running, injury-prevention

I am looking for some stretches that I can do before runs and ones after runs that can ward off shin splints. I am pretty susceptible to getting them while training for a 10K or 10 miler. I have supportive shoes and inserts to support my high arches, but I really need to gain strength and/or perform stretches consistently.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I feel your pain (literally)

Answer (score 4):

Shin splints are commonly caused by imbalances in muscles and supporting tissue.  Try these for strengthening and mobility.

1) Alphabet with your feet focusing on rotating your ankles.
2) Towel toe curls or picking up change with your toes.
3)  Heel raises.
4)  Calf raises.

More detail about the above can be found at [Exercises to Prevent Shin Splints](http://christopherickes.com/running-blog/how-to-cure-shin-splints-from-running/).  For stretching, use these [Calf Stretches](https://www.google.com/search?q=calf%20stretches&hl=en&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=ptyhT4OvJ4Ok8gSZgL3dCA&sqi=2&ved=0CEwQsAQ&biw=1366&bih=600).  Do following a run for 3 minutes to a side in order to lengthen the calf muscles.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the links. I've been running for a couple of weeks, 3 times, and I've noticed them creeping up.